# Blank browser screen even with correct permissions. Bug?

Tags: 2013, permissions, bug, read, contribute

I had a user who couldn't see a few pages / lists even though she had full rights to read and contribute. The page would be blank (no error) if she tried loading them. In order to fix this, I had to add her to the site collection administrators, then immediately remove her, meaning none of her permissions actually changed. She can now load the pages and see the lists.

I guess I'm just wondering if anybody has had this problem? Is it a known bug? This could be happening to other users (no reports of it yet) and I just want to be proactive about it.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a group called Pages view group and app all users to this group. Give this group read permissions to your master page and css file in sharepoint designer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding her to the Site Owners group for the collection? That would give her Full Control rights over the site without giving her access to the site admin settings.

If you haven't yet then give it a try. If she still can't see the site collections with Full Control permissions then I suggest you check which pages and lists she can and can't see and check their Audience Targetting settings. They may be set to be only visible to specific users but Site Collection Administrators would, of course, be exempt from those rules.

Answer (score 1):

One of my user also faced same problem. We done following activities: 
1. Clean the browser cache and try to access site once again (No success).
2. Log-in other machines as well but there is no success.
3. Removed user permissions on a specific site and re-assign(No Success)

Root cause for this problem is the calendar of the user. If it is not set to "Gregorian" the user will receive a blank page.
Please contact with farm level admin for resolve the issue. After reset the user Calendar he can able to see some thing on his browser.